# unable to install meld in redhat linux 5.10

Tags: linux, redhat, meld

I came to know that Meld is wonderful tool for comparing files. I have downloaded meld's latest tar ball from https://download.gnome.org/sources/meld/3.14/.
While running setup.py, I got below error

```
 sudo python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 6, in ?
    import meld.build_helpers
  File "/scratch/asubbiay/softwares/meld-3.14.1/meld/build_helpers.py", line 196
    target_dir = self.frozen_target if os.name == 'nt' else self.target
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please let me know, what I'm doing wrong.
Note: We are in restricted environment, yum installation is not working.

thanks.

Comment: What is your python version `python -V`?

Comment: @juned. Its Python 2.4.3

Comment: Ohh well according to the doc you need `Python 2.7` and as it's using older version its giving you those errors. I suggest you to install 2.7 and then try

Comment: @juned I have tried with python 2.7.10, but facing below error when running install.
`intltool-update -p -g meld
ERROR: xgettext failed to generate PO template file because there is non-ASCII
       string marked for translation. Please make sure that all strings marked
       for translation are in uniform encoding (say UTF-8), then *prepend* the
       following line to POTFILES.in and rerun intltool-update:

           [encoding: UTF-8]

error: command 'intltool-update' failed with exit status 1`